# Deleting User specific information from log file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I have to delete user specific information from all the log files, i.e. username, email, and phone number.

These information, however, can be in a different column for each log file; furthermore, the log files don't have any specific format.

For example a log file is like this:

```
CustomerID City     Cname   CPhone   Cemailid
1234       SEA  George 4468689901 goerge@xyz.com
2234       NYK  Jose   7712393223 jose@abc.com
```

whereas another one is like this:

```
Customername CustID email         Phone     city
Philip       3345  phil@qqq.com 2233442233 VEG
Tom          2267  tom@kkk.com  8877343434 DAL
```

Is there any idea through which we can find an approach?

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problem, so kindly do add the same in your question.

Comment: You haven't specified how the columns are separated. If they are separated the same way as the words in a single field, then you have a problem, because Mr `York Jose` could live in the fantastic city of `New`. So as a best bet we could assume the fields are tab separated.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis apologies NewYork would be single word, I updated it and the columns are separated via space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know in advance how the log files' headers can be, there's little you can do **to** the headers and **with** the headers.

As a consequence, without knowing how to leverage the header lines, you cannot distinguish between `Philip` living is `Seattle` and Mr `Seattle` living in `Philip` city, and all you can do is devise some ways to recognize some of the fields.

This, for instance, recognizes the e-mail by matching a `@` and phone 
 by matching more than 4 digits, and then deletes these columns in all lines except the header line.

```sh
awk '
NR == 1 { print; next }
NR == 2 {
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
    if (match($i,/@/)) { email = i }
    if (match($i,/^[0-9]{5,}$/)) { phone = i }
  }
}
{
  $email = ""
  $phone = ""
  print $0
}'
```

However, if you **do** know that the header of the user-specific columns always match some regex, then you can do this:

```sh
awk '
NR == 1 {
  for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
    if (match(tolower($i),/name/)) { name = i }
    if (match(tolower($i),/phone/)) { phone = i }
    if (match(tolower($i),/mail/)) { mail = i }
  }
}
{
  $name = ""
  $mail = ""
  $phone = ""
  print $0
}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this would only delete email address and not name and phone number

Comment: @CodeHeapsters, can you try putting the `awk` script (i.e. the part between single quotes `'`) in a file `script` and then use it as in `awk -f script logfile.txt`? If that does not work either, please, include the output of `awk --version` at the end of your question.